# Problem Sending an Email with inline Image

Tags: c#, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an inline image in my email and it displays fine but instead of just displaying the image I also receive the same image as an attachment. How do I get it to just have the email inline and not have a separate attachment.

Here is my code:

```
 public async static Task SendMail(string emailAccount, string sendTo, string message, string subject, string imgpath)
        {
            try
            {
                string internalEmail = emailAccount;
                string emailPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"];
                string displayName = "Church Musician Team";
                MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
                myMessage.To.Add(sendTo);
                myMessage.From = new MailAddress(internalEmail, displayName);
                myMessage.Subject = subject;
                string attachmentPath = imgpath;
                Attachment inline = new Attachment(attachmentPath);
                inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
                inline.ContentId = "id1";
                inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
                myMessage.Attachments.Add(inline);
                myMessage.Body = message;
                myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
               



                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtp.EnableSsl = false;
                    smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailHost"];
                    smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPort"]);
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(internalEmail, emailPassword);
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.SendCompleted += (s, e) => { smtp.Dispose(); };
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(myMessage);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/667568/sending-email-with-linkedresource

Comment: This really helped me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the bitmap data right into the body using:

```
public static string BmpToUrl(Bitmap source)
{
    return $"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) (new ImageConverter()).ConvertTo(source, typeof(byte[])))}";
}
```

Then wherever you want to actually place it in the body use:

```
...
body += $"<img src='{BmpToUrl(myBitmap)} />"
...
```

This way you don't need to have a separate attachment.

Admittedly I've never actually done this in an email but I believe that it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! How could you do this if you have an email template? Is there anyway to put this in the template or does it have to go in the method? That was the reason why I tried doing it the other way like in my question because it allowed me to place it directly in my template

Comment: You could put this right into a template you just have to capture the Base64 encoded string representation of the Bitmap so that you can embed it into the template.

Comment: I just implemented your answer and realized that there is already a class that does this for you called LinkedResource. Chetan Ranpariya posted a great link to do this. Your answer is correct but it's actually a part of Linked Resource. Thank you for your help :)